# Parsing text based on whitespace using Python

Tags: python, regex, parsing, split

```
            No time. Not today.
                (slides in last bullets)
            Ten, eleven, twelve... or bust.
                (chambers a shell into each
                 gun, looks up)
            Right here!

The cab SCREECHES to a stop on the shoulder of the highest
FREEWAY in a massive INTERCHANGE of freeways. Dopinder halts
the meter and hands Deadpool his CARD.
```

My goal is to parse the above text such that the dialogue is separated from the description. There are multiple instances of this in my file. The output should be two separate strings `x` and `y`, where:

```
x = "No time. Not Today...Right Here!"
```

and

```
y = "The cab SCREECHES...his CARD"
```

How can I achieve this using Regular Expression matching? Or is there a better way to solve this? I'm using python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that two consecutives line breaks are the separator of the sections of the text, so you can split it:

```
x, y = s.split('\n\n')
```

You can also find out whether a variable is dialog or not by checking its first characters. If they are spaces (i.e. there is indentation) then it's a dialog:

```
x.startswith('            ') # True if dialog, False otherwise
```

If you need to remove extra whitespaces before and after each string, use `strip`:

```
x, y = [x.strip() for x in s.split('\n\n')]
```

By doing so you won't be able to check if something is dialog, so be sure to check it before removing whitespaces.

Comment: Once I do this, is there a way for me to check which is dialogue and which is narrative based on indentation?